# Does CMake have the concept of ifdef endif

Tags: cmake

I am working with a sub project, which most of the time will be used together with another CMake project. I wonder if CMake has something like

```
ifndef cmake_minimum_required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
endif
```

basically, if `cmake_minimum_required` has already been defined somewhere, in my sub project I want to use what has been defined, otherwise, I want to define `cmake_minimum_required` in my sub project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CMake policy [`CMP0000`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/policy/CMP0000.html) to tell whether `cmake_minimum_required` has already been called.

When `cmake_minimum_required` is called, `CMP0000` is automatically set to `NEW`, so you can do:

```
cmake_policy(GET CMP0000 MinimumVersionIsSet)
if(NOT MinimumVersionIsSet STREQUAL "NEW")
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
endif()
```

The only way I can see this failing is if a higher-level CMakeLists.txt contained something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0000 OLD)
```

before calling `add_subdirectory` for your project.  This would effectively set the policy to `NEW` then immediately set it to `OLD`.  However, I feel this is a highly unlikely scenario, since the policy would only be set to `OLD` to allow the omission of a `cmake_minimum_required` call.

Having said all this, I think your approach may be slightly risky.  Say the top-level project sets the minimum required version to 2.6 and you require features only available in 2.8.  Since your `cmake_minimum_required` call is skipped, users running CMake 2.6 would receive more mysterious failure messages (about unknown CMake commands) instead of the more concise "CMake 2.8.11 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.6.0".